# Permutation inverse form

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, symmetric-groups

Given:

$A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$,

$P_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2& 3& 4& 5& 6\\
2& 3& 4& 1& 5& 6\end{pmatrix}$,

$P_2=\begin{pmatrix}1 &2 &3 &4& 5 &6\\
       1 &3 &5& 4& 6& 2\end{pmatrix}$.

*(i)* Find $P_2^2$.

**My answer:**
$$
P^2_2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}1& 2& 3& 4 &5 &6\\
 1& 5& 6& 4& 2& 3\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Is this correct?

*(ii)* $(P_1∘P_2)^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6\\
      2 &4 &5 &1 &6 &3\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$

How to complete it? That is, how do I find the inverse?

Comment: I don't understand question I or II, what is p2(2-a square above)?

Comment: i cant find a small square symbol above the P2..sorry@ModdedBear

Comment: oh, here is a mathjax guide http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Also, why does the permutation contain repeated elements?

Comment: @Janice For (i) do you mean find $P_2^2$? As in $P_2 \circ P_2$? And what do you mean by "how to complete it by -1 form"? Do you mean how to find $(P_1 \circ P_2)^{-1}$, the inverse of $(P_1 \circ P_2)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(i) is correct.

And for the second one you just see from the co-domain to domain..

that is,

\begin{align}
(P_1\circ P_2)^{-1}&=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6\\
2&4&5&1&6&3\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
2&4&5&1&6&3\\
1&2&3&4&5&6\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5&6\\
4&1&6&2&3&5\end{pmatrix}\end{align}